# A word for when you're discussing a topic and then take a detour to another topic before coming back to the topic at hand

Tags: single-word-requests

It's a word professors like to use when they talk about a topic and spontaneously decide to discuss a related topic before coming back to the main topic. I cannot seem to remember the word for that though. Detour is not the word I'm thinking of, but it's something in the same vein.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Digression* fits the circumstances you describe. It is the act of leaving the main subject you are writing or talking about, then writing or talking about something else before returning to the first theme. Dictionary definitions abound and I need not repeat them here, having now (I hope) awakened your memory.